# "Only God knows God's miso soup". Is this a pun?

Tags: japanese-language, saint-oniisan

[image: saint oniisan chapter 11]

In this chapter Buddha got cold, so Jesus tried to cook something for him. So he came up with a miso soup, and a joke. Or so it seems. But I don't understand this joke. "Only God knows God's miso soup". Is this a pun?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, this is a Japanese pun**. Unfortunately, this pun doesn't translate well to other languages.

The original phrases in Japanese are:

[image: kaminomi s/zo shiru]

<sup>Image from [buzz-manga.blog.jp](http://buzz-manga.blog.jp/Saint-Oniisan.html)</sup>

> 神【かみ】のみぞ知る【しる】 (*kami nomi zo shiru*, only God knows)
>   神【かみ】のみそ汁【しる】 (*kami no miso shiru*, God's miso soup)

Yes, both have the same reading: *kaminomi[s/zo]shiru* (except *so* and *zo*, which only differs by [a voicing mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakuten_and_handakuten)).

Also, the one that Jesus does in that scene is called [*dajare/oyaji gag*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dajare), which usually employs the same reading for different meaning.